# Error when using AliasToBeanResultTransformer in Criterion

Tags: nhibernate-criteria

I am trying to do some paging together with some fetching, but the result returns duplicates. I have therefore added a AliasToBeanResultTransformer, but then I get the following error:

*Could not find a setter for property 'this' in class 'ForumThread'*

```
var crit = Session.CreateCriteria<ForumThread>()
                .Add(Expression.Eq("IsActive", true))
                .AddOrder(new Order("LastForumPost", false))
                .SetFirstResult((page - 1)*pageSize)
                .SetMaxResults(pageSize)
                .SetFetchMode("ForumPosts", FetchMode.Eager)
                .SetFetchMode("ForumTagRelations", FetchMode.Eager)
                .SetCacheable(true)
                .SetResultTransformer(new NHibernate.Transform.AliasToBeanResultTransformer(typeof (ForumThread)));
return crit.List<ForumThread>();
```

What might I be missing?

Comment: I solved this by just not using that transformer.  I didn't set it at all, and it just sorta worked.  :\

Answer (score 0):

To avoid duplicates you need to use `DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer`, not `AliasToBeanResultTransformer`